# Confusion Regarding subgroups of $P(\mathbb{N},\triangle)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading about the group $P(\mathbb{N},\triangle)$ where $P(\mathbb{N})$ denotes power set of Natural Numbers, and $\triangle$ denotes symmetric difference

I encountered the following fact :

There are countably infinite subgroups of finite order in $P(\mathbb{N},\triangle) \ldots (1)$

I am confused with the above fact ,suppose I   consider a subgroup of order $2$, then

$H = \{\phi, X\}$, where $X$ is any random non identity element of $P(\mathbb{N}, \triangle)$

Since every element of the given group is of order $2$, so for this $X$  I have uncountable number of choices, hence there exist uncountable number of subgroups of order $2$.

So, statement $(1)$  should be incorrect ?

Can someone please clear this confusion ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think your original statement (1) is incorrect.

Comment: (1) sounds incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, (1) as it stands is false, since any subset of $\mathbb N$ works.

I do, however, suspect that the problem actually meant the group where we restrict subsets of the naturals to be finite subsets; this can be easily checked to be a group, and is also countably infinite (as is the number of order 2 subgroups, since a countable union of countable sets is countable).

Answer (score 0):

As the OP demonstrated, one may clearly define a bijection from $P(N)$ to the subgroups of order 2. Let $S \subseteq N$, then the map $S \to \{\emptyset, S\}$ is a bijection:

**(Injective):** Let $\{\emptyset, S\} = \{\emptyset, T\}$, then clearly $S = T$.

**(Surjective):** Let $H = \{\emptyset, S\}$ be an element in the codomain, then $S$ clearly maps into $H$.